# Moving To New Line In Haskell - Updated

Tags: haskell

I have the following functions in Haskell that must print the sales of weeks. Each sale in a new line. But it is not working the way i expect it to. The problem i have is the newline character '\n'.

Code:

```
printWeeks :: Int->String
printWeeks 0 = printWeek 0
printWeeks x  = printWeeks(x-1) ++ printWeek x 

printWeek :: Int->String
printWeek x = show(x)  ++  "  " ++ stars (sales x) ++ "'\n'"
```

I have tried many ways but the new line character is not working as expected. Everything is printed on the same line whichis not what i want.

Need help?

thanks

**UPDATE**

The following is not working because of compile errors. The errors comes from the second line of formatLines. The type decalaration is causing errors. Need help here

```
formatLine :: (Name,Price)->IO()
formatLine (a,b) = putStrLn (a ++ dots ++ p) 
                   where
                   x=(length a)
                   p=(formatPence b)
                   y=length p  
                   z=lineLength-(x+y)
                   dots = printDots z 


formatLines :: [(Name,Price)]->IO()
formatLines []= ""
formatLines (a:x) = formatLines x ++ formatLine a
```

Comment: `"'\n'"` is a three character string -- a list of a single quote, then a newline, then a single quote.  What you want is `"\n"` which is a string containing only one character, a newline; that string is the list `['\n']`, what it contains is `'\n'`.  Your string was `['\'','\n','\'']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a riddle why so much action is happening under the heading of `IO`. This is maybe a little verbose.  I couldn't tell where `lineLength` was coming from so I made it a parameter.

```
formatLine :: Int -> (Name,Price) -> String
formatLine linelength (name, price) =  name ++ dotfill ++ showprice 
  where 
  showprice :: String
  showprice = formatPence price
  extra :: Int
  extra = linelength - length (name ++ showprice)
  dotfill :: String
  dotfill = replicate extra '.'

formatLines :: Int -> [(Name, Price)] -> String
formatLines linelength []= ""
formatLines linelength (first:rest) = 
  (formatLine linelength first ++ "\n") ++ formatLines linelength rest

standardPrint :: [(Name, Price)] -> IO ()
standardPrint listing = putStrLn (formatLines 50 listing)

fileAwayPrices :: FilePath -> [(Name,Price)] -> IO()
fileAwayPrices filename listing = writeFile filename (formatLines 70 listing)

testlist :: [(Name,Price)]
testlist = [("oats",344),("barley", 299),("quinoa",599)]

-- *Main> standardPrint testlist
-- oats...........................................344
-- barley.........................................299
-- quinoa.........................................599


type Name = String
type Price = Integer
formatPence n = show n
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `++ "\n"` to append a newline to the output; your current code will add a `'`, then a newline, then another `'`.

As @marcog points out, be sure to use `putStr` to print it out (or don't append the newline at all and use `putStrLn`). Example:

```
Hugs> putStr (show 4 ++ "\n")
4

Hugs> putStrLn (show 4 ++ "\n")
4


Hugs> print (show 4 ++ "\n")
"4\n"
```

(Note that the Hugs interpreter adds extra newlines after each output.)

Comment: thanks for your reply. How do i declare the types above my function definitions

Answer (score 2):

You are probably printing the string using `print x`, which is equivalent to `putStrLn (show x)`. `show x` is converting the newlines into readable characters `\` and `n`. You need to use `putStrLn x` instead, or `putStr x` if you don't want to append a newline to the end of the string.

You should also remove the single quotes you have around the newline, unless that was intentional.

Comment: thanks for your reply. How do i declare the type? i have something like this for the first two lines and they are given errors:  formatLines :: [(Name,Price)]->IO()
formatLines []= ""

Comment: @Kap Sorry, I don't have enough haskell knowledge to help you there. I suggest asking a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Re your update: your type declaration is correct, it's the rest of `formatLines` that's wrong.

```
formatLines :: [(Name,Price)]->IO()
formatLines [] = return ()
formatLines (a:x) = formatLines x >> formatLine a
```

A more concise way of writing that is

```
formatLines :: [(Name,Price)]->IO()
formatLines = mapM_ formatLine . reverse
```